# What does this image onload function do?

Tags: javascript

I came across this snippet, and it seems quite unconventional to me, can anyone help me explain what's the purpose of it? Thanks in advance.

```
image.onload = image.onerror = function () {
entry[name] =
image =
image.onload =
image.onerror = null;
delete entry[name];
};
```

Comment: When an image has an error delete all events tied to it and `entry[name]`.

Comment: @KJPrice Thanks! But what image does load successfully? Can you also write it as an answer, so I can vote you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpret that as:

> when image loads *or* has an error, remove any other events tied to
>   the image and also delete `entry[name]`.

You can "chain" properties so that they all have the same value:

```
this.name = 'bob';
this.age = '21';

this.name = this.age = null; /* <<---Both properties are now null*/
```